# Ring formations catalyzed by piperidinium acetate: Robinson annulation?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

Hey everyone, I have a question about the mechanism below. Do you guys think the Robinson annulation is a good starting point for the 6-C ring on the right? If not, what would you suggest me for this mechanism? Thank you

Comment: Do you have any thoughts beyond the Robinson annulation?

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! Your question will likely be considered as homework and be voted down. You need to make some effort to answer the question yourself. Take a look here about homework policy. PS: You need to do more than toss in a name reaction. You can resubmit your more detailed analysis. Try tracing the 16-membered ring of the reactant in the product. I have an answer waiting for you.

Comment: I started numbering Cs from the one coming after N counter-clockwise. After that I tautomerized b keto ester attached to C12 to obtain an enol, but I do not think OAc is strong enough to pull H from there. So I might need another perspective here. After that, I attacked C7 (double-bond) with the enol pushing double-bond between C5-C6 an also O- at C5. I then tautomerized it again to obtain a ketone which I attacked with amine group in ring. I deprotonated and protonated N and O at C5, respectively and removed water from C5. Later, I tautomerized the ketone at C11 and attacked C5 from C10.

Comment: It looks like you have good idea of what is going on! It is also possible that the imine formation is precedes the addition of $\ce{C12 to C7}$. I'll post my thoughts in the future; the hour is late.

Comment: Identifying the acidity of the $\beta$-keto ester is correct. That forms a nucleophilic species, so you should look for electrophilic positions. There are enough substituents that it will be really helpful if you can map the carbons in both of the backbones. In general, one does that transpose carbons. Only go that route if you've exhausted simple possibilities. And if it's not obvious, there are multiple steps involved here...

Answer (score 5):

Esra: As I said in my Comment, you have the right idea about what bonds to make to form the final product **2**. The catalyst, piperidinium acetate, has both acidic and basic properties that facilitate enolization and dehydration. There are two principle reactions to be considered: a Mannich and a vinylogous Mannich reaction. The possibility of an initial Michael addition may be an alternative but the arguments for that route are the same whether or not the iminium salt **3** is formed first or not. I'm surprised that the macrocycle **1** exists as the free amine because there are too many reactions it could undergo. One of which is the carbinol amine formed by the addition of the amino group to the $\ce{C5}$ carbonyl. Under the influence of the catalyst, the vinylogous iminium salt **3** is formed with the loss of water. This species, which is a better electrophile than an α,β-unsaturated ketone, allows for the enol of the β-ketoester moiety to form the $\ce{C7-C12}$ bond. Given the stereochemistry at $\ce{C8 and C9}$, there are four possible stereoisomers that could conceivably form: two *trans-* and two *cis*-isomers. The *trans*-$\ce{C7-C12}$ isomers will not lead to **2** because the final ring closure is prohibited by the remoteness of $\ce{C5 and C10}$ from one another. Of the two cis-isomers, only **4** leads to product **2**. The fate of the other cis-isomer will be addressed later.

﻿﻿[image]

The *E*-double bond in **1** or **3** may also be converted to a *Z*-isomer by 1,4-addition/elimination of acetate or piperidine. Structures **5a** and **5b**, ignoring the $\ce{C8-C9}$ substituents for the moment, are enantiomeric. When the substituents are considered, **5a** and **5b** are diastereomeric conformations. The sequence **5a** $\rightarrow$ **6** $\rightarrow$ **2** leads to the the observed product via formation of the "red bonds." However, the pathway **5b** $\rightarrow$ **7** $\rightarrow$ **8** has problems. In the transition state for the formation of the $\ce{C7-C12}$ bond, there is a developing steric interaction between the -CO<sub>2</sub>Et and the -OBn groups. Structure **7** is the other cis-stereoisomer of **4** alluded to earlier. Even if the formation of **7** were successful, the last ring closure, $\ce{C5-C10}$, is fraught with a severe steric interaction between the $\ce{C4}$-methylene and the $\ce{C9}$-methyl group. These interactions are best viewed in the diastereomer **8** that is not formed.

﻿﻿[image]